# phonegap build - facebook connect I get a Alert in FB.init

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
try {
FB.init({
appId : "*********",
nativeInterface : CDV.FB, 
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
useCachedDialogs : true
});
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
}, false);
```

Even when I try to run this code in debug I get alert "Error!"

Comment: I didn't see any alert "error" in your code.

Comment: I know! And it drives me crazy

Comment: rilex my friend, try scan word Error! for each files. take it slow.

Comment: FB._nativeInterface = options.nativeInterface;
    if (FB._nativeInterface) {
      FB._nativeInterface.init(FB._apiKey, function(e) {alert('Error!');});
    }

Comment: If I change the alert in console.log(e) I get this:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined"}`

Comment: already include cordova.js?

Comment: Yes,
the error come from facebook-js-sdk.js